# Excel fill table from one cell

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I'm trying to make Excel work better for me, but I'm stuck at a problem.  I have one sheet with a lot of data:

[image]

Unfortunately I have to report the data like this

[image]

Ideally I would like to be able to fill in 'B' and the rest of the values would fill in. H,I and K i fill in manually. But the being able to enter a value in B and getting the corresponding values would be amazing. I have tried using IF functions and a VBA without success.

Comment: Why don't you use a formula with [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)? Should be possible without using VBA.

Comment: Agree with @Peh. Vlookup with different column parameters will return what you need. Have you tried it? You will have a hard time because of the merged cells, so you will have to make a lot of adjustments to the formula from section to section, but that's what you have to deal with when you use merged cells. Avoid merged cells.